# MySQL Query to get Data of Specific Item by All Months

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I have a table 3 Tables (Orders, Order_details, Products)

**Orders**

```
id  |  order_date
1   |  March-01-13
2   |  March-02-13
3   |  April-01-13
4   |  May-01-13
5   |  June-01-13
and so on.....
```

**Order_Details**

```
id  |  order_id  |  product_id | total_price
1         1            1            100     /*mouse*/
2         1            3            200    /*monitor*/
3         2            2            50     /*keyboar*/
4         2            3            200    /*monitor*/
and so on....
```

**Products**

```
id  |  title
1      mouse
2      keyboard
3      monitor
and so on...
```

**And here is my SQL Query that giving unexpected output**

```
SELECT title, SUM(total_price) as total_price, orders.order_date as date
FROM products
LEFT JOIN order_details
ON order_details.product_id=products.id
LEFT JOIN orders
ON orders.id=order_details.order_id
WHERE title='monitor'                    /*this is just a try, prod_id should be the one*/
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
ORDER BY total_price DESC LIMIT 10
```

What I want to get is the total_price of product_id in all months

**Expected Output**

```
title    | total_price | date
monitor      400         March
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a GROUP BY, all of the fields in the SELECT list need to either be aggregated, or be part of the GROUP BY.  So try adding the 'title' to the group by, and adding the MONTH function to the order_date in the SELECT list as follows:

```
SELECT title, SUM(total_price) as total_price, MONTH(orders.order_date) as date
FROM products
LEFT JOIN order_details ON order_details.product_id=products.id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id=order_details.order_id
WHERE title='monitor'                   
GROUP BY title, date
ORDER BY total_price DESC LIMIT 10
```

This will get the total_price for each product for each month.

Comment: Thanks. It works. How about the "total_price" of every day of that Month?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT p.title, SUM(total_price) as total_price
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     order_details od
     ON od.product_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.id = od.order_id
GROUP BY p.title
ORDER BY total_price DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I don't see why your sample output would have a month in it.

Comment: Month is will be needed for my chart's data. so it must have a month, i think.